# iOS safari different than iOS desktop shortcut to same website

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, safari, iphone-web-app

I made a webapp that has a spinner while the login form is submitted using javascript, the spinner stays on the page until the page switches. I have tested this with Safari, Chrome, Firefox on an actual computer, on Chrome and a Desktop shortcut on android, and with a desktop shortcut and on Safari for iOS.

On Safari for iOS the spinner disappears after only a second even if the login takes 2-3 seconds, but on the same device if I use the Desktop shortcut it will stay the entire time. Is there a reason that I am getting different functionality from the same webapp from the same device?

Comment: what is "Desktop shortcut" ?

Comment: When you are on a website you can make a shortcut and add it to your desktop, it appears like an app that you can click on and it will go to that website.

Comment: if you don't tell the spinner to go away, then it's due to when the browser clears the viewport before rendering the next page, and how long that new page takes to render. leaving up a stale page is the browser's choice, and not something you can explicitly control unless you prevent a redrawn page alltogether using ajax or pushState.

Comment: @dandavis do you know why it clears the javascript off the viewport before the html/css? The spinner will disappear about 1 second before the rest of the page, then it will switch pages.

Comment: i don't know, but if i had to guess: it might be an artifact of tearing down the page. the spinner was last up, so it might be first down. or maybe a class is changing that hides the spinner, and other browsers freeze the js sooner as the page reloads. you can try logging events or changes via cookie/localStorage and see if you can detect such happenings, but that doesn't mean it's fixable. hmm, maybe do the asctual submit in a setTimeout() just after the spinner is shown...